# Fetch the CSS of a resource (page/post/etc)

Tags: plugins, rest-api

I created a page, which is a basic page that shows a `This is the home page` text. I styled that text with a red background and white color text. Now, when I fetch the page using the REST API of Wordpress (`/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/1`), I get the content from the page with the classes but I don't get the styles reference meaning that when rendering the content in my React application It's just a paragraph with plain text without the styles I created in the Wordpress editor.

How can I fetch those?

I'm attaching the image of how it looks like in my Wordpress editor (That's not global styles or theme styles since I'm using the default theme)

[image]

Here I'm adding the styles:

[image]

Comment: when you mention CSS, where did you set the CSS? There are lots of ways to set CSS or change the background colour and padding of a paragraph, it's not clear which method you used, use the edit link underneath the tags to add more information to your question. You also mention you're using the default theme, but there are many default themes, are you using the 2024/23/22 or one of the older themes?

Comment: Hi @TomJNowell! When I mention CSS I'm refering to when you add styles to a block within the wordpress editor :) I updated the issue with another image

Comment: ooh in that case they usually show up as HTML classes, you'd still need to provide CSS for those, but in the situation that they render inline CSS though if it's not in the rendered HTML version then that's still an open question. More context on why you're trying to fetch the pages though and where they're being fetched to would help here, especially to avoid answers that don't apply to you. These are just comments though rather than a written answer you can accept

Comment: Yeah! That's what I saw a couple of days ago but I was wondering on how do I get those classes to be actually applied :(. Basically I want to use Wordpress as headless with React, and for that I'm just consuming the endpoint that Wordpress enables. There maybe is a better way to fetch styles, but I still can't find a way through that because I have almost none experience with Wordpress

Comment: Tried doing a request to `/v2/themes` but apparently I'm unauthorized to see the themes even though I have the administrator role.

Comment: if the CSS is in a stylesheet you'll need to include that, and you can't get that information via the themes endpoint because the CSS is specific to that page displayed using that theme. Note that most of these options can be disabled or forced via `theme.json`. There is also a chance that there is no way to do this, especially since the same post could have different CSS depending on where and how it's displayed, especially with blocks being server rendered rather than static HTML

Comment: @TomJNowell what do you recommend doing? They want to work with Wordpress as Headless

Comment: if I had a good recommendation I'd have written an answer. Until you find one, disable all those options via `theme.json` as I suggested in my previous comment. Just because WP offers you shadows and gradients etc doesn't mean you have to support or expose them to editors. Also re: `/v2/themes` just because you're logged in as an admin doesn't mean visiting REST API endpoints automatically makes them authenticated, you have to have _both_ a cookie session _and_ a REST API nonce, or use an application password